# How to reload Zend Captcha image on click refresh button?

Tags: php, zend-framework, captcha

I apply a zend captcha in my php page now i require to add captcha reload button. Please give answer according to zend.

Comment: This is the default behavior of Zend_Captcha. Could you provide some example code to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just two quick snippets but I think you will get the idea. Adjust the element name and the selectors for your needs.

In your controller add a method to generate a fresh captcha

```
public function refreshAction()
{
    $form = new Form_Contact();
    $captcha = $form->getElement('captcha')->getCaptcha();

    $data = array();

    $data['id']  = $captcha->generate();
    $data['src'] = $captcha->getImgUrl() .
                   $captcha->getId() .
                   $captcha->getSuffix();

   $this->_helper->json($data);
}
```

In your view script (I'm using mootools for the ajax-request)

```
document.addEvent('domready', function() {
     $$('#contactForm img').addEvent('click', function() {
        var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
            url: "<?= $this->url(array('controller' => 'contact', 'action' => 'refresh'), 'default', false) ?>",
            onSuccess: function(captcha) {
                $('captcha-id').set('value', captcha.id);
                $$('#contactForm img').set('src', captcha.src);
            }
        }).get();
    });
});
```

Edit: Added pahan's jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#refreshcaptcha').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: '/contact/refresh', 
            dataType:'json', 
            success: function(data) { 
                $('#contactForm img').attr('src', data.src); 
                $('#captcha-id').attr('value', data.id); 
            }
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks for the code, works like charm :) after reading this I did it using jquery. `$(document).ready(function() { $('#refreshcaptcha').click(function() { $.ajax({ url: '/contact/refresh', dataType:'json', success: function(data) { console.log(data) $('#contactForm img').attr('src',data.src); $('#captcha-id').attr('value',data.id); } }); }); });`

Comment: @pahan You're welcome. I added your jquery script to my answer for later reference. thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem may i know your refreshcaptcha is what element, mine is img but i wont work?

Answer (score 2):

@user236501 Actually it can be any type of Zend Form Element (for example Button). You're even able to put clickable refresh link as Zend_Form_Element_Captcha description option like this:

```
        $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
            'label' => 'Some text...',
            'captcha' => array(
                'captcha' => 'Image',
                'wordLen' => 6,
                'timeout' => 300,
                'font' => './fonts/Arial.ttf',
                'imgDir' => './captcha/',
                'imgUrl' => 'http://some_host/captcha/'
            ),
            'description' => '<div id="refreshcaptcha">Refresh Captcha Image</div>'
        ));
```

but in that case `Description` decorator's options should be modified, for example:

```
        $this->getElement('captcha')->getDecorator('Description')->setOptions(array(
            'escape'        => false,
            'style'         => 'cursor: pointer; color: #ED1C24',
            'tag'           => 'div'
        ));
```

It can be done in form's `init()` method.
Sorry for my english. Btw I'm not sure if I put my comment in the right place ;)

Answer (score 1):

@Benjamin Cremer
thanks for the code, works like charm :)
after reading this
I did it using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#refreshcaptcha').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/contact/refresh',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#contactForm img').attr('src',data.src);
                $('#captcha-id').attr('value',data.id);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In `config/autoload/global.php` add the following

   ```
   'view_manager' => array(
       'strategies' => array(
           'ViewJsonStrategy','Zend\View\Strategy\PhpRendererStrategy'
       ),
   ),
   ```
2. in `YourModule/src/YourModule` create a new folder `Ajax`
3. Inside `Yourmodule/Ajax` create a file `AjaxController.php`

   ```
   namespace YourModule\Ajax;

   use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
   use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
   use YourModule\Forms\SignupForm;

   class AjaxController extends AbstractActionController
   {          
       public function refreshSignupCaptchaAction(){
           $form = new SignupForm();
           $captcha = $form->get('captcha')->getCaptcha();             
           $data = array();                
           $data['id']  = $captcha->generate();
           $data['src'] = $captcha->getImgUrl().$captcha->getId().$captcha->getSuffix();
           return new JsonModel($data);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add route inside `module.config.php`

   ```
   'yourmodule-ajax' =>array(
           'type' => 'segment',
           'options' => array(
           'route' => '/yourmodule/ajax/:action',
               'constraints' => array(    
                   'action' => '\w+',
               ),
               'defaults' => array(
                   'controller' => 'YourModule\Ajax\AjaxController',
               )                  
           ),
       ),
   ```
5. last in your template, I assume you are using jquery

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
       <div id="captcha" class="control-group <?php echo count($form->get('captcha')->getMessages()) > 0 ? 'has-error' : '' ?>">
           <?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('captcha')); ?>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
               <a id="refreshcaptcha" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Refresh</a>
               <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('captcha')); ?>
               <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('captcha')); ?>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){

       $('#refreshcaptcha').click(function() { 
           $.ajax({ 
               url: '<?php echo $this->url('yourmodule-ajax', array('action'=>'refreshSignupCaptcha')) ?>', 
               dataType:'json', 
               success: function(data) { 
                   $('#captcha img').attr('src', data.src); 
                   $('#captcha input[type="hidden"]').attr('value', data.id); 
                   $('#captcha input[type="text"]').focus(); 
               }
           }); 
           return false;
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```